# Join Multi Index Dataframe and single index dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two types of dataframes i.e multi-indexed which is:

```
Code_1  pk1           pk2
Code_2  X     Y   Z   X   Z
Col_1   120  10   1   1   2
Col_2   15    2   3   5   6
```

and single indexed dataframe which looks like

```
Code1  col_3   col_4   col_5
pk1    xyz     xyz     xyz
pk2    xyz     xyz     xyz
pk3    xyz     xyz     xyz
```

I want to merge it into a dataframe in such a way that it looks like

```
Code1  col_3   col_4   col_5  X_Col_1  X_Col_2  Y_Col_1  Y_Col_2  Z_Col_1  Z_Col_2
pk1    xyz     xyz     xyz    120       15        10        2        0        0
pk2    xyz     xyz     xyz     1         3        0         0        2        6    
pk3    xyz     xyz     xyz     0         0        0         0        0        0
```

How to do it with most efficient way? P.S I have unique values of Code_2 so I can make extra columns. But how to merge it this way?

Comment: Can you post the output of `df.to_dict()` for both dataframes? Makes it a bit easier to copy-and-paste in the presence of multiindices

Comment: @ignoring_gravity
For first dict `{('pk1', 'X'): {'Col_1': 120, 'Col_2': 15},
                     ('pk1', 'Y'): {'Col_1': 10, 'Col_2': 2},
                     ('pk1', 'Z'): {'Col_1': 1, 'Col_2': 3},
                    ('pk2', 'X'): {'Col_1': 1, 'Col_2': 5},
                      ('pk1', 'Z'): {'Col_1': 2, 'Col_2': 6}}`

For second dict `{'Code1': {0: pk1, 1: pk2, 2: pk3}, 
                           'col_3': {0: 'xyz', 1: 'xyz', 2: 'xyz'},
                           'col_4': {0: 'xyz', 1: 'xyz', 2: 'xyz'}, 
                           'col_5': {0: 'xyz', 1: 'xyz', 2: 'xyz'}}`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a combination of `unstack` and `pivot`:

```
df1 = df1.unstack().reset_index().rename({"level_0": "Code1"}, axis=1)
df1["new_col"] = df1.level_1 + df1.level_2
df1.pivot(index="Code1", columns="new_col", values=0).reset_index().merge(
    df2, on="Code1", how="outer"
).fillna(0).reindex(
    columns=[
        "Code1",
        "col_3",
        "col_4",
        "col_5",
        "XCol_1",
        "XCol_2",
        "YCol_1",
        "YCol_2",
        "ZCol_1",
        "ZCol_2",
    ]
)
```

It will give you

```
    Code1   col_3   col_4   col_5   XCol_1  XCol_2  YCol_1  YCol_2  ZCol_1  ZCol_2
0   pk1     xyz     xyz     xyz     120.0   15.0    10.0    2.0     2.0     6.0
1   pk2     xyz     xyz     xyz     1.0     5.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
2   pk3     xyz     xyz     xyz     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```